# How to configure IntelliJ to keep FXML imports on separate lines?

Tags: intellij-idea

When formatting an FXML file, IntelliJ puts all the imports on the same line. Here is an image of what it looks like:

[image: FXML imports are on a single line]

What configuration changes need to be made to keep each import on it's own line? I want it to format like this:

[image]

This is for IntelliJ 14.1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more trial and error:

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML -> Other -> Keep line breaks

Check the checkbox.

It is probably a bug that import statements are condensed to a single line when the checkbox is unchecked. After all, when the "Keep line breaks" checkbox is unchecked, the IDE does not get rid of *all* line breaks. I think xml imports would be kept on individual lines in this scenario. I'll file a bug with Jetbrains.